# What's the trick to get the limit of a sequence with roots like $a_n = -3n + \sqrt{9n^2+11n+16}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I know of some "tricks" for limits of sequences like

$$b_n = \frac{n^2+7}{3n+1} = \frac{n^2+7}{3n+1} \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}} = \frac{\frac{n^2}{n^2}+\frac{7}{n^2}}{\frac{3n}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^2}}$$

Surely, there has to be a trick like this for the above example $a_n = -3n + \sqrt{9n^2+11n+16}$? Thanks. :-)

Comment: Trick is to rationalize / to multiply top and bottom by conjugate.

Comment: The trick is to multiply by $$\frac{3n + \sqrt{9n^2+11n+16}}{3n + \sqrt{9n^2+11n+16}}$$ to get $$\frac{11n+16}{3n + \sqrt{9n^2+11n+16}} \to \frac{11}{6}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in the comments,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{a_n}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\bigg(-3n+\sqrt{{9n^2}+11n+16}\bigg)}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\bigg(\bigg(-3n+\sqrt{{9n^2}+11n+16}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{-3n-\sqrt{{9n^2}+11n+16}}{-3n-\sqrt{{9n^2}+11n+16}}\bigg)\bigg)}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\bigg(\frac{9n^2 - ({9n^2}+11n+16)}{-3n-\sqrt{{9n^2}+11n+16}}\bigg)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\bigg(\frac{-11n - 16}{-3n-\sqrt{{9n^2}+11n+16}}\bigg)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\bigg(\frac{11n + 16}{3n+\sqrt{{9n^2}+11n+16}}\bigg)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\bigg(\frac{11 + (16/n)}{3+\sqrt{9+(11/n)+(16/n^2)}}\bigg)=\frac{11+0}{3+\sqrt{9+0+0}}=\frac{11}{3+3}=\frac{11}{6}.$$

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks! :-) I even had the first steps - rationalizing the numerator - already but somehow confusingly thought, the root in the fraction's denominator would still mess it up. Works just fine now. Again, thanks

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to "rationalising the denominator" is
$$
\begin{align}
-3n+\sqrt{9n^2+11n+16}
&=-3n+3n\sqrt{1+\frac{11}{9n}+\frac{16}{9n^2}}\\
&=-3n+3n\left(1+\frac{11}{9n}+O(n^{-2})\right)^{1/2}\\
&=-3n+3n\left(1+\frac{11}{18n}+O(n^{-2})\right)\\
&=\frac{11}{6}+O(n^{-1}).
\end{align}\
$$

Comment: This looks interesting. Could you elaborate on what's going on from line 2 to 3? Are you using the coefficients from Pascal's triangle but for ${...}^\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: It's just $(1+x)^b=1+bx+O(x^2)$ as $x\to0$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
 -3n + \sqrt{9n^2+11n+16}&=\frac{(-3n + \sqrt{9n^2+11n+16})(-3n - \sqrt{9n^2+11n+16})}{-3n - \sqrt{9n^2+11n+16}}\\
&=\frac{9n^2-(9n^2+11n+16)}{-3n - \sqrt{9n^2+11n+16}}
\end{align*}